# PHP: GD graphics library (Boutell) extension: why the shift from pixels to points from GD 1 to GD 2

Tags: php, gd, pixel, points

This may well be a stupid or outdated question, but upon stumbling upon the following page:

https://www.php.net/imagettfbbox

I cannot help but ask, what was the reason for changing the units of the size parameter
from pixels to points. Does this change have an implication from a practical standpoint?
I am really curious. Thanks.

Comment: because pixels have different sizes depending on the screen density. points are points and have no direct relationship to pixels except a specified conversion factor for the display medium.

Comment: Fair enough. But that means that this function must have knowledge of the screen pixel density of the screen in which the browser user agent is running. How can this be possible? Judging form its parameter arguments the aforementioned imagettffbox function does not take this into consideration. Unless I send this information in an HTTP header, and this information is somehow passed to imagettfbbox behind the scenes, but I don't know of any such mechanism, so I even doubt imagettfbbox could work in such way. Anyone have any ideas about this?

Comment: it is weird. if gd was producing vector images it'd be useful, but since it's a raster-only library, I don't know why it switched to points. you'd probably have to check the GD project pages, because GD is just a plugin for PHP, it's not a PHP project itself.